# MSTeams tab app working on desktop, browser and iOS, but not working on Android

Tags: android, tabs, microsoft-teams

I am working on a tab app for MSTeams. I've got everything working as expected on desktop app, on a browser and on iOS. However, when I try to access the tab on an Android device it seems that `entityId` is overwritten.

This is what I have in `registerOnSaveHandler()`:

```
    microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {
        microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
            websiteUrl: "https://{{ teams_app_domain }}/",
            contentUrl: "https://{{ teams_app_domain }}/msteams/content/?name={loginHint}&tenant={tid}&group={groupId}&channelId={channelId}&teamSiteDomain={teamSiteDomain}&entityId={entityId}",
            entityId: config,
            suggestedDisplayName: "Display Name"
        });
        saveEvent.notifySuccess();
    });
```

Which is matching what the docs says the handler expects. I've tried updating the `websiteUrl` and making it exactly the same as `contentUrl` as this article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/design/tabs-mobile) suggested, but this didn't work either.

However, I found these two issues on GitHub (from early last year), which exactly match the behaviour I am seeing

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/1335

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/1251

Those two are marked as resolved, but I think that the issue is still active.

If anyone had experienced that or knows a workaround and wants to share it - it will be highly appreciated

Comment: This issue is fixed and it's being rolled out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying it without ANY url parameters - try to get the context using the Teams `Context` object instead, on the page. This has the added advantage that certain private info isn't shared via the request itself (querystring values will be reported to the in between servers, I think, whereas the traffic itself won't, and in this case it includes your user's login name).

On a related note, when you use `setSettings` it is setting the *final* url for the tab. It does *not* vary per user. However, you're setting `loginHint` based on the user who is configuring the tab. This means that if you're using that value to try do something *per user*, it will actually show the values for that *first* user only (the URL does NOT get set for every visitor, only on that first user of `setSettings`.

So, like I said, consider doing everything with the Teams context instead, or at least making sure you don't mind what goes in the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is due to a bug, you can check the details [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/1335)